# Why am I bleeding memory?

Tags: python, audio, memory, detection, recording

heres a script to detect and record sound that ive been hacking on for a while. it works great, except that its memory usage grows after every successful detection. i fixed a similar issue that occurred during prolonged periods of silence (`if num_listening > 4096:`...), but this one has me stumped.

```
from sys import byteorder
from array import array
from struct import pack
from datetime import datetime

import pyaudio
import wave
import os
import time

THRESHOLD = 6348
MAX_SILENCE = 500
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100
MAX_LENGTH = 1024

def is_silent(snd_data):
    "Returns 'True' if below the 'silent' threshold"
    return max(snd_data) < THRESHOLD

def normalize(snd_data):
    "Average the volume out"
    MAXIMUM = 16384
    times = float(MAXIMUM)/max(abs(i) for i in snd_data)

    r = array('h')
    for i in snd_data:
        r.append(int(i*times))
    return r

def trim(snd_data):
    "Trim the blank spots at the start and end"
    def _trim(snd_data):
        snd_started = False
        r = array('h')

        for i in snd_data:
            if not snd_started and abs(i) > THRESHOLD:
                snd_started = True
                r.append(i)

            elif snd_started:
                r.append(i)
        return r

    # Trim to the left
    snd_data = _trim(snd_data)

    # Trim to the right
    snd_data.reverse()
    snd_data = _trim(snd_data)
    snd_data.reverse()
    return snd_data

def add_silence(snd_data, seconds):
    "Add silence to the start and end of 'snd_data' of length 'seconds' (float)"
    silence = [0] * int(seconds * RATE)
    r = array('h', silence)
    r.extend(snd_data)
    r.extend(silence)
    return r

def record():
    """
    Record a word or words from the microphone and 
    return the data as an array of signed shorts.

    Normalizes the audio, trims silence from the 
    start and end, and pads with 0.5 seconds of 
    blank sound to make sure VLC et al can play 
    it without getting chopped off.
    """
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE,
        input=True, output=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)

    num_silent = 0
    num_snd = 0
    num_listening = 0
    snd_started = False

    r = array('h')

    while num_snd < MAX_LENGTH:
        # little endian, signed short
        snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE, exception_on_overflow = False))
        if byteorder == 'big':
            snd_data.byteswap()
        r.extend(snd_data)

        silent = is_silent(snd_data)

        if not silent and not snd_started:
            snd_started = True

        if snd_started:
            num_snd += 1
            if num_silent > MAX_SILENCE:
                break

        if silent:
            if snd_started:
                num_silent += 1
            if not snd_started:
                num_listening += 1
                if num_listening > 4096:
                    del r[:]
                    num_listening = 0

    sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    del r[0:8000]

    r = normalize(r)
    r = trim(r)
    r = add_silence(r, 0.5)
    return sample_width, r

def record_to_file(path):
    "Records from the microphone and outputs the resulting data to 'path'"
    sample_width, data = record()
    data = pack('<' + ('h'*len(data)), *data)

    wf = wave.open(path, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(1)
    wf.setsampwidth(sample_width)
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(data)
    wf.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("Ready!")
        recorded = datetime.now()
        recorded = "testpi1_" + recorded.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S") + ".wav"
        record_to_file("/motion/" + recorded)
        os.system("./convert-audio.py " + recorded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forking the `record_to_file` function with `multiprocessing.Process` solved the issue.

add

```
import multiprocessing
```

adjust

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("Ready!")
        recorded = datetime.now()
        recorded = "testpi1_" + recorded.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S") + ".wav"
        record_to_file("/motion/" + recorded)
        os.system("./convert-audio.py " + recorded)
```

to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("Ready!")
        recorded = datetime.now()
        recorded = "testpi1_" + recorded.strftime("%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S") + ".wav"
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=record_to_file,args=("/motion/" + recorded,))
        p1.start()
        p1.join()
        os.system("./convert-audio.py " + recorded)
```